# Function for most frequent level of string or factor categorical variable in R

Tags: r

I have a function that finds the most frequent level of string and factor variables. This is used in a `data.table` aggregation on Big Data, for non-numeric columns.

Right now the overall aggregation runs extremely slow. I'm trying to make improvements in other aspects as well (reducing observations and columns, etc) and I would like to see if there's a want to improve this function:

```
MaxTable <- function(InVec, mult = FALSE) {
  if (!is.factor(InVec)) InVec <- factor(InVec)
  A <- tabulate(InVec)
  if (isTRUE(mult)) {
    levels(InVec)[A == max(A)]
  }
  else levels(InVec)[which.max(A)]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function isn't very complicated so I don't know how much more efficient you can get.  However, maybe removing the `if` and `else` states may help.  How about something like this?

**Code**

```
# Sample Data
dat <- c("a", "a", "b", "c", "d","a", "a", "b", "c", "d","a", "a", "b", "c", "d","a", "a", "b", "c", "d","a", "a", "b", "c", "d")

# Mode function
MaxTable <- function(x){
     dd <- unique(x)
     dd[which.max(tabulate(match(x,dd)))]
}
```

**Output**

```
> MaxTable(dat)

[1] "a"
```

How many variables are you trying to process? You may want to think about writing a function that splits up the number of obs. for parallel processing, tabulate the mode for each section, merge each section, and then do `which.max()` .  Although, I'm not sure if you are reaching the limits of R.  Also, maybe a database such as `mysql` would be another option.